# Need to build a query with column names stored in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table as shown below. This table will be generated dynamically and I have no prior idea about what value it is going to hold.

```
------------------------------------------
TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME    CHAR_LENGTH
------------------------------------------
 EMPLOYEE          COL1             100
 EMPLOYEE          COL2             200
 EMPLOYEE          COL3             300
 EMPLOYEE          COL4             400
```

Based on this table, I want to build a query in such a way that it would give me those columns, that contains data having char length greater than `CHAR_LENGTH` column value.

For example if `COL2` contains data having char length 500 (>200), then query would give me `COL2`.

I don't have any draft code to show my attempt, as I have no idea how would I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in pure SQL due to the dynamic nature of your requirement.  You'll need some form of PL/SQL.

Assuming you're ok with simply outputting the desired results, here is a PL/SQL block that will get the job done:

```
declare
  wExists number(1);
begin
  for rec in (select * from your_dynamic_table)
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*)
                         from dual
                        where exists (select null
                                        from ' || rec.table_name || ' t
                                       where length(t.' || rec.column_name || ') > ' || rec.char_length || ')'
    into wExists;

    if wExists = 1 then
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.column_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

You'll also notice the use of the `exists` clause to optimize the query, so as not to iterate over the whole table unnecessarily, when possible.

Alternatively, if you want the results to be queryable, you can consider converting the code to a pipelined function.

Comment: Takes lesser time when compared in same environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_name
from (
 select statement that builds the table output
) A
where char_length<length(column_name)
```

will that help?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a procedure to achieve the same :

Here I am treating the `all_tab_columns` table in Oracle, which is a default table with much similar structure as your reference example.(Try `select * from all_tab_columns`). The structure of all_tab_columns is much like yours, except that you will never find a varchar record whose value has exceeded its data length(obvious database level constraint). Date fields may exceed data length, and do reflect in this procedure's output. I am searching all columns in EMPLOYEES whose size exceeds what is specified.

```
DECLARE
cursor c is select column_name,data_length,table_name from all_tab_columns where table_name=:Table_name;
V_INDEX_NAME all_tab_columns.column_name%type;
v_data_length all_tab_columns.data_length%type;
V_NUMBER PLS_INTEGER;
v_table_name all_tab_columns.table_name%type;
 BEGIN
open c;
    LOOP
     FETCH c into v_index_name,v_data_length,v_table_name;
          EXIT when c%NOTFOUND;
          v_number :=0;
execute immediate 'select count(*)  from '|| :Table_name ||' where length('||v_index_name||')>'||v_data_length into v_number;
 if v_number>1 then
 dbms_output.put_line(v_index_name||' has values greater than specified'||' '||V_INDEX_NAME||' '||v_data_length);
 end if;
 END LOOP;
 close c;
 END;
 /
```

Replace all_tab_columns and its respective columns with the column name of your table.

**DEFECTS :** The table name is hardcoded. Trying to make the code generic execute immediate or any other trick. Will achieve soon.
**EDIT** : Defect fixed.